# Split worksheet.name using active cell values from a temp worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a hard time figuring out how to name a worksheet using an active cell value.

I am using a code that was written by Ron de Bruin on filtering out data and splitting it into different worksheets. See below link for reference on the code

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_4.htm

I have tried to use the step into function within the VBA editor to determine where the worksheet name comes from and ive noticed that the code uses the first row of a newly created worksheet. (ws2)

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim My_Table As ListObject
Dim ErrNum As Long
Dim ActiveCellInTable As Boolean
Dim CCount As Long
Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet

'Select a cell in the column that you want to filter in the List or Table
'Or use this line if you want to select the cell that you want with code.
'In this example I select a cell in the Gender column
'Remove this line if you want to use the activecell column
Application.GoTo Sheets("SplitInWorksheets").Range("K7")

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "This macro is not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rng = ActiveCell

'Test if rng is in a a list or Table
On Error Resume Next
ActiveCellInTable = (rng.ListObject.Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0

'If the cell is in a List or Table run the code
If ActiveCellInTable = True Then

    Set My_Table = rng.ListObject
    FieldNum = rng.Column - My_Table.Range.Cells(1).Column + 1

    'Show all data in the Table/List
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ' Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Table.ListColumns(FieldNum).Range.AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
```

The above code looks at cell k7 and returns all unique values in that column.

**Example:**

In the original worksheet i have something like this:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
1                             2
1                             2
2                             3
3                             4
```

In the created temp worksheet(ws2) i get this:

```
 A 
 2
 3
 4
```

This then loops and filters out data from my original worksheet based on the criteria in Column A from the newly created temp worksheet (ws2) and creates new worksheets with the filtered data.

```
  'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Table.Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
                                                                  Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Table.ListColumns(1).Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0

            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data to a new worksheet." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = "Sample " & cell.Offset(0, 10).Value & " NIIN " & cell.Value
```

Now when it reaches this part of the code

```
  Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = "B " & cell.Offset(0, 10).Value & " A " & cell.Value
```

The worksheets get named as:

"B (BLANK) A 2"

"B (BLANK) A 3"

"B (BLANK) A 4"

However i would like it to be named as:

"B 1 A 2"

"B 2 A 3"

"B 3 A 4"

I see the issue lies within the created temp worksheet (ws2) where it only returns the A column values because B does not exist.

Would it interfere with the filter if i have the contents of column A from my original worksheet copied over to the temp worksheet(ws2) ?

If this does not make sense please ask for more information.

Comment: TLDR. Given the ask, I dont see how all this code is relevant.

Comment: Does the word `Blank` really get added to the name? Or is it juts `B A 2`?

Comment: @urdearboy i wasnt sure if the code would be beneficial or not. Do you suggest that i remove it? the word Blank does not get added it is B A 2. I should have made that part clear. Apologies

Comment: Code seems way over complicated for what you are trying to achieve.. atleast what I think you are trying to achieve.. I'm doubting myself because what `I think` you want is just to add sheets with incrementing name.. is it?

Comment: @urdearboy: good shout!

Comment: @Zac to my understanding, the worksheets are named based on what is on the temp worksheet(ws2) The values from the temp worksheet is copied over from a specific column in the original worksheet with the data. The temp worksheet then filters the data one row at a time using the advanced filter and creates a new worksheet and gives it the cell value name that it filters it with.

Comment: What i was trying to accomplish is have the worksheets named based on two cell values on the original worksheet. Is there a way to have the cell value of column k and column a copied over to the temp worksheet(ws2) and then filtered only on the column A from the temp worksheet(ws2) and when the code creates the name for the worksheets, to also be able to find the cell value in B for the naming purposes.

Comment: Can you provide sample of your worksheets?

Comment: So in your first pic there are two rows with a 1 in column A and 2 in column K. If repeated values in A always correspond to repeated values in K perhaps use a dictionary to create your unique values rather than advanced filter and then you could store the K value alongside the A value. Does that make sense?

Comment: @zac definitely. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @SJR it makes sense. Is there a site i can reference on how to do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which may start you off.

```
Sub x()

Dim oDic As Object, v, r As Range

Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With oDic
    For Each r In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        oDic.Item(r.Value) = r.Offset(, 10).Value
    Next r
    For Each v In .keys
        MsgBox "B " & .Item(v) & " A " & v
    Next v
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

There is lots of material online on VBA scripting dictionaries, e.g. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/ (I can't vouch for this site, it just came top in Google).

Comment: will dictionary allow me to then filter by the K column and extract the data corresponding to it? I believe the advanced filter code provided by Ron is used for that purpose. I will give this a go and report back. Thank you.

Comment: I missed your comment, but take it this answer helped you. Does it answer your question above?

Comment: After reading more on dictionaries i believe it will help me. I am currently figuring out a way to use it. Thank you SJR.

Comment: OK, my pleasure. Post another question if you have a specific problem.